# How to correctly SELF JOIN tables in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, self-join

I want to refer the employees to their manager.

I got two examples here. Both of them give me a solution that I don't want.

First self join query:

```
select m1.naam as medewerker, m2.naam as manager
from medewerkers m1, medewerkers m2
where m1.medewerker_id = m2.manager
order by 1;
```

Screenshot of solution:

[image]

now I am only getting all the managers and not the employees

Second self join query:

```
select b.naam as employee, a.naam as manager
from medewerkers a right outer join medewerkers b on(a.medewerker_id = b.manager);
```

Screenshot of solution:

[image]

This will result in the same as above with the extra employees. The problem is that the employees are not referred to their managers (managers are still referred to their self).

At the moment this is what I insert into my DB. Maybe there could be a problem with my insert value. Because the given awnsers won't work

--Employee

```
insert into MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values(11111112, 'Joost', 'Eindhoven Langloopstraat 1', 0678765478, 1500, 'baliemedewerker', 10, null);
insert into MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values(11111119, 'Rick','Gemert. Dunneweg 76', 0678768315, 2200, 'Manager', 10, 11111119);
```

Comment: You should edit your query and show (1) the results that you *do* want and (2) sample data going into the query.

Comment: Yes your insert is wrong.  `manager` should be `11111119` on the first record and `null` on the second.

Comment: the manager should be the one with the numbers on the end, instead of a null value. I hope I make sense. Now I see that I am referering a manager to himself but how else could I fix this? I kind of a noob in this :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either got the join backwards or pulling from the wrong sides (depending on how you look at it).  If you use different table aliases it becomes more apparent:

```
select emp.naam as medewerker, man.naam as manager
from medewerkers emp, medewerkers man
where emp.medewerker_id = man.manager   --asking for rows where the employee is the manager's manager!
order by 1;
```

change your join order (and use proper join syntax):

```
select emp.naam as medewerker, man.naam as manager
from medewerkers emp
INNER JOIN medewerkers man
    ON emp.manager = man.medewerker_id 
order by 1;
```

Here's the proper statements to fix your bad input data:

```
insert into MEDEWERKERS 
    (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values
    (11111112, 'Joost', 'Eindhoven Langloopstraat 1', 0678765478, 1500, 'baliemedewerker', 10, 11111119);

insert into MEDEWERKERS 
   (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values
    (11111119, 'Rick','Gemert. Dunneweg 76', 0678768315, 2200, 'Manager', 10, null);
```

Comment: All the solutions won't work. I think it is my insert value that is not correct. Could you take a look at it?

I updated my question

Comment: Yes it looks like your insert is wrong - you are not assigning a manager to the employee (Joost) and the manager (Rick) is assigned to himself.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I get that now, thanks for that. Any idea how to fix this? should I give this manager a different number or what should I do?

Comment: @MaximedeLange Garbage in, Garbage out - fix the source data.   `manager` should be `11111119` on the first record and `null` on the second.

Comment: Sorry to ask. I am a little bit slow today. Could you give me an example of how to correctly implement the insert statement? Because I get what you are saying, but I cannot implement it somehow :S. sorry to ask

Comment: @MaximedeLange I have added the proper insert statements to my answer so they're formatted better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I marked your solution as the best given one!

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem the `Rick/Rick` line and so on?  If so, you can replace the manager name with `NULL` by fixing the `on` clause:

```
select e.naam as medewerker, m.naam as manager
from medewerkers e left join
     medewerkers m
     on m.medewerker_id = e.manager and
        m.medewerker_id <> e.medewerker_id
order by 1;
```

Or, because the problem might be duplicates in the original table, you might want:

```
select e.naam as medewerker, m.naam as manager
from medewerkers e left join
     medewerkers m
     on m.medewerker_id = e.manager
where e.medewerker_id <> e.manager     
order by 1;
```

Comment: --MEDEWERKERS
insert into MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values(11111112, 'Joost', 'Eindhoven Langloopstraat 1', 0678765478, 1500, 'baliemedewerker', 10, null);
insert into MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values(11111119, 'Rick','Gemert. Dunneweg 76', 0678768315, 2200, 'Manager', 10, 11111119);

Comment: Sorry I pressed the wrong button mate. I just wanted to update my post :).
anyhow this is my insert value I think there lies a problem. instead of your solutions